# Automatically feed data from multiple columns to another sheet's multiple rows

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in Excel:

Sheet1: Contains a list of names, month of payment and the payments made by them i.e Name, House No, Payment.  **(3 columns)**

Sheet2: Contains a receipt format which is going to be printed. It has three fields empty which are Name, House No, Payment. **(3 rows)**

What I want to do is when a list is made manually in Sheet1, the data from there automatically goes to Sheet2 and places itself in its respective places i.e name from Sheet1 to name in Sheet2.
I studied VLOOKUP and INSERT and MATCH but I'm not getting the hang of it.

Can someone please explain how things should work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that for printing *a* receipt you only want one row fro one sheet into one column of another at a time, so in your second sheet, assuming `Name` is in A1 on each sheet, select B1:B3 and:

```
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A2:C2)
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This replicates whatever is in Sheet1 A2 into Sheet2 B1, in Sheet1 B2 into Sheet2 B2 and so on.

Alternatively in Sheet2 B1:

```
=Sheet1!A2
```

in Sheet2 B2:

```
=Sheet1!B2
```

in Sheet2 B3:

```
=Sheet1!C2
```

Comment: Umm no, transpose is not what I'm looking for. Actually i'm making this program for a person who has very basic knowledge of excel so I want the data to automatically feed itself in the receipt without the person having to feed in the formula every time.